# optimize php code that uses youtube api to get youtuber video 'uploadstatus' using curl library in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, curl, youtube-api

My app primarily uses youtube videos, and now my task is to eliminate youtube videos that do not play ,i.e, private or deleted by user etc... so i wrote a script as follow:

```
function badvideos()
    {
        $ids=array();
        $query=$this->db->query("select Id,VideoUrl from  VideoTable where Status=1"); //Status=1 means active videos
        $res=$query->result();
        foreach($res as $val)
        {
            $status="";
            $videoid=$val->VideoUrl;             //getting each video videourl
            $videoid=explode('=',$videoid);      
            $videoid=$videoid[1];                //getting videoid
            $videourl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?    
            part=status&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&id=".$videoid."&key=Myapikey";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$videourl);
            $output=curl_exec($ch);                   //curl execution

            $response = json_decode($output, TRUE);
            foreach($response['items'] as $value)
            {
                $status=$value['status']['uploadStatus'];
            }
            if($status!="processed")                  //if bad video
            {                                    
                $ids[]=array("id"=>$val->Id,"videourl"=>$val->VideoUrl);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($ids);       //showing json response of bad videos 'videourls
    }
```

**the code is running alright whan i have to execute on 100 records or less... for 3000 records it took me 20 mins....but what if i have to run on 50,000 records....**

Is there a way to optimize the code for better performance or an alternative to scan thousands of records from database and check its 'uploadstatus'......Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you running this on localhost? also there are limits for requests via yt api, but 50k records (units) is nothing I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running CURL in parallel to fetch multiple requests at the same time,

This can be done using the [Curl Multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) implementation

See [Example Code](http://www.askapache.com/php/curl-multi-downloads.html)

Note that you don't have to be authenticated in order to know what videos had been deleted, so can use this link instead

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}
```

And save some authentication time